# how does cin.get() function works?

Tags: c++, arrays, cin

**I would like to know how does cin.get() function works?**

For example, I have char array of 256 characters. If input contains less than 256 characters, what's 'empty' array elements containing then? Is every unused element is '\0' or what?

Thanks in advance,
Janis

Comment: One nul terminator will be added, I.e. if you read 5 characters into a 256char buffer, then a nul terminator will be written to the 6th element(or 5th if we're counting a 0th element) of your buffer. Anything beyond that will be left untouched, if it's unitialized memory then it just remains that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, You have a simple code and you entered a string "ex: Hello world!" as follow:

```
char str[256]; // Uninitialized variable
std::cin.get(str, 256);
```

The result:

[image]

The same code but with initialized variable:

```
char str[256] = {}; // Initialized variable
std::cin.get(str, 256);
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The part of the array that is not filled is untouched. If the array is fresh, typically you see zeros, as the operating system zeros out newly allocated pages. Consider this an artifact, expect *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

`get()` is an overloaded function of the `basic_istream` class. Assuming you are calling it like:

```
cin.get(array, size)
```

Then it will fill up to `size - 1` characters in the array. The rest are leaved unmodified, so you cannot know the value they have.

Answer (score 0):

> If input contains less than 256 characters, what's 'empty' array elements containing then? Is every unused element is '\0' or what?

It depends.

Global and static variables are default initialized. Local variables are uninitialized - unless you explicitly initialize them.

```
char buf1[256]; // global variable, all zeroes

int main() {
    char buf2[256]; // uninitialized memory
}
```

Reading from `buf1` has well defined behavior but reading from `buf2` has not, so if you `std::cin.get(buf2, <some_size>);` and read from the memory beyond the `\0` that `std::cin.get()` puts in your array, your program will have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

To amend that, you can default initialize your local variables too:

```
int main() {
    char buf2[256]{}; // default initialized memory
}
```